# Printing a xml like structure from looping arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is a question about arrays and how to loop them.

I have these two arrays:

```
$arrayHeaders = array ('ID', 'DATE', 'NAME', 'STUDIES');
$arrayInformation = array (array('30540000000', '1998/05/05','Dave Mars','Philology'), 
array('30430000000', '2003/07/07','Sarah Scuassi','Translation'));
```

I need to loop them in order to print something like this:

```
echo "<".$header.">".$info."</".$header."><br>";
```

How can I do that? Please notice that $arrayInformation may have much more sub arrays than two.

Many thanks

Comment: Will the two arrays always be equal length? I would recommend using one associative array instead if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is nesting two foreach loops:

```
foreach ($arrayInformation as $values) {
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($arrayHeaders[$key])) {
           $tag = $arrayHeaders[$key];
        } else {
           $tag = '?';
        }
        printf('<%s>%s</%s>', $tag, $value, $tag);
    }
}
```

See it working [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PTMfJk). (You need to check the sourcecode...the "tags" don't show up properly.)

In case `$arrayHeaders` contains too few entries, the output will be `<?>foo</?>` for the missing fields.

Comment: Why are you doing $tag = '?'; In case there's no headers?

Comment: @user712027 Exactly. You can do whatever you want there, I just opted for this very simple solution to avoid an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$arrayHeaders = array ('ID', 'DATE', 'NAME', 'STUDIES');
$arrayInformation = array (array('30540000000', '1998/05/05','Dave Mars','English Philology'), 
array('30430000000', '2003/07/07','Sarah Scuassi','Translation and Interpretation'));

foreach($arrayInformation as $data) {
    for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        echo "&lt;".$arrayHeaders[$i]."&gt;".$data[$i]."&lt;/".$arrayHeaders[$i]."&gt;<br/>";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: `xml` not `html`, so better change `&lt;` to `<` etc.

Comment: I realized that `<` and `>` tags are skipped by my browser (Chrome). As I understood the OP want only to display the array as XML and not using it.

Comment: they are not ;) check the source Chrome thinks its html so it parses everything as `DIV`'s add `header('Content-Type: text/xml');` to your file to show it correctly and of course `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` then it will work :D

Comment: You are right. Maybe I misunderstood the question. According to me the OP want only to display these arrays as an XML data (instead of a table for example) and he will not use it in his code, I has only a visualization purpose. So, I don't think that he want to add additional headers to his script for XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arrayHeaders as $header) {
    foreach($arrayInformation as $info) {
        echo "<".$header['ID'].">".$info[0]."</".$header['ID']."/>";
        echo "<".$header['DATE'].">".$info[1]."</".$header['DATE']."/>";
        echo "<".$header['NAME'].">".$info[2]."</".$header['NAME']."/>";
        echo "<".$header['STUDIES'].">".$info[3]."</".$header['STUDIES']."/>";
    }
}
```